# How to display overlined letters in .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode

I am thinking about creating custom Number Formatter that will return string that represents integer in [Old Armenian Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_numerals). Before arrival of Indian numerals (0,1..9) to Europe, Armenians were counting in by using national alphabet. It was much like to Roman one by its ideology. There were not Zero. Letters are representing units(1,2,3..9), tens (10,20..90), thousands (100,200..900) and so on. As because in Armenian alphabet at that time was 36 (limited) letters you can count from **1** to **9999**. Then they extended by adding overlined letters.

How can I retrieve string that contains overlined letters?

Comment: The Wiki page simply draws an overline line over them :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell How did you do? I wasn't able to paste the diacritical mark...

Comment: Wait... Done through the editor of the Visual Studio 1̅2̅3̅4̅

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [COMBINING OVERLINE' (U+0305)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/305/index.htm) It is a combining diacritical mark, so alone is invisible. You put it AFTER each number you want with the overline.

In C#: `"Ա\u0305"` for example, should be 10000.

As a small note, finding a font that has bot the Combining Overline and the Armenian numbers will be complex. Sadly combining diacritical aren't 100% supported everywhere, and it seems that font substitution doesn't work very well when you try to use them (or perhaps you can't have two font substitutions at the same time, one for the Combining, and one for the Armenian number...)... So the trick Gravell did on the comment works, the Armenian number can be shown, the Armenian number + the Combining Overline? Complex!

For example Chrome isn't even able to show the Combining Mark over the Armenian Numerals. Firefox and IE 10 are (but even them move too much to the right the Combining Mark)

> 1̅      Ա̅      2̅      3̅

Comment: They work will for Arabic numerals but not that much for Armenian letters.