# Overline in console programming

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, math, roman-numerals

Just a quick question. For the roman numerals above `3999`, we used to represent them using a overline. For representing `4000`, we will be using the following:

[image]

So, to display this overline, what should I do? Also, please advice me which of the above is right?

---

**Update #1**

I saw somewhere that we can use Unicode Characters by using the following code:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine("H\u0305");
Console.WriteLine("\u0305H");
Console.ReadLine();
```

After putting this code, I have set my console to use `Consolas` font at `14pt`. I got this output:

[image]

I was expecting either of the code to show me a combined version, but no avail.

Comment: I image you'll have to use some double spacing, putting an underscore `_` on the first line

Comment: @Jonesy Good idea, but tough. Something better? Can keep as a last option.

Comment: There is a 'Combining Overline' , see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127029/how-to-display-overlined-letters-in-net), but getting it to work in the console is gonna take some luck.. If you succeed, do post your findings!! - On your other question: I would much prefer the 1st version.

Comment: I tried to combine, but didn't work! `:(` I am updating the question.

Comment: @TaW I have updated the question, please check.

Comment: I'm not surprised, even many or most browsers have trouble displaying these combining characters right; (there are others, like underline and bows.) [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237666/adding-text-decorations-to-console-output) post sounds as if there really is __no__ way. (Other than doublespacing or using colors)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the console?  You can't.  Drawing to the console in such a manner is not possible as the console only supports characters.

One does exist in Unicode (as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline)) but this is merely an overlined space.

Comment: Not drawing, but any characters or the specified set of characters with an overline?

Comment: @PraveenKumar There is an overlined space as you can see in the link I gave you in the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar As I stated in my answer `In the console? You can't. Drawing to the console in such a manner is not possible as the console only supports characters.`

Comment: I know buddy, what can I do? When something is NOT possible, we can't do anything about it. Thought of other solutions too, nothing worked. Just waiting for someone to implement something. Let's see! `:)` Thanks for your effort though@